# Why alias works with vue and doesn't work with jest?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, jestjs

I have a front-end built in typescript with vue2 and I'm trying to add some tests with jest (*v27.5.1*) in my app.

I have a model with a import of another model :

```
// assets/vue/models/Dashboard.ts
import City from '@/models/City';

export default class Dashboard {
    cities: City[] = [];
}


// assets/vue/models/City.ts
export default class City {
    name: string| null = null;
    postcode: string|null = null;
}
```

The compilation with webpack-encore works great and I have no error in my code. But when I ran `jest`, I have this error :

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/models/City' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I do not understand why I have this error, because in Dashboard.test.ts, I use my vue component using the alias, like this : `import Dashboard from '@/components/Dashboard.vue';`

There is my jest configuration, located in package.json :

```
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "ts",
        "json",
        "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
        ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
        "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/assets/vue/$1"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/assets/vue/tests/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(js|ts)$",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
        "<rootDir>/assets/vue/jest.setup.ts"
    ]
}
```

The project structure is the following :

```
package.json
assets/vue
        |
        |__components (all .vue files)
        |__models (all models .ts)
        |__tests (all tests)
```

If someone has any solution for this error, I'm fully blocked on

Comment: Could you add the contents of `@/models/City`?

Comment: assets/vue/models/City.ts contains :

`export default class City {
     name: string| null = null;
     postcode: string|null = null;
}`

I have updated my question for a better presentation.